# Menu doesn't display while creating it in GTK+ 3 C

Tags: c, gtk, stack-overflow, text-editor

[Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWsTL.png)

i am new with gtk+. while learning to create menus in gtk+ i simply copy paste the following code and when i run it....i don't know what is the problem but only it shows window. it does not show any menus or menu bar... help me if anyone has been through this problem...

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    GdkPixbuf *create_pixbuf(const gchar * filename)
    {
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    GError *error = NULL;
    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(filename, &error);
    if (!pixbuf) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error->message);
    g_error_free(error);
    }
    return pixbuf;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *icon;
    GtkWidget *vbox;

    GtkWidget *menubar;
    GtkWidget *fileMenu;
    GtkWidget *fileMi;
    GtkWidget *quitMi;
    GtkWidget *text_view;
    GtkWidget *buffer;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Write Pad");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500, 400);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    icon = create_pixbuf("Web.png");
    gtk_window_set_icon(GTK_WINDOW(window), icon);

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);


    text_view = gtk_text_view_new ();
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), text_view, 1, 1, 0);

    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (text_view));



    menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
    fileMenu = gtk_menu_new();

    fileMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("File");
    quitMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");

    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(fileMi), fileMenu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(fileMenu), quitMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), fileMi);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);


    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quitMi), "activate", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);



    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the code. All of the variables you declare use the `GtkWidget *` type, while the functions `create_pixbuf` and `gtk_text_view_get_buffer` return data of the `GdkPixbuf *` and `GtkTextBuffer *` types. You also use a deprecated function.

Moreover, you call the menu related functions after the `GtkTextView` related functions, thereby placing the menu at the bottom of the window.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GdkPixbuf *
create_pixbuf (const gchar *filename)
{
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    GError    *error = NULL;

    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file (filename, &error);

    if (!pixbuf) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free (error);
    }

    return pixbuf;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget     *window;
    GdkPixbuf     *icon;
    GtkWidget     *vbox;

    GtkWidget     *menubar;
    GtkWidget     *fileMenu;
    GtkWidget     *fileMi;
    GtkWidget     *quitMi;
    GtkWidget     *text_view;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    icon = create_pixbuf ("Web.png");

    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Write Pad");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 500, 400);
    gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_icon (GTK_WINDOW (window), icon);

    vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);

    menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new ();
    fileMenu = gtk_menu_new ();

    fileMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("File");
    quitMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Quit");

    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu (GTK_MENU_ITEM (fileMi), fileMenu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (fileMenu), quitMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (menubar), fileMi);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    text_view = gtk_text_view_new ();
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), text_view, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (text_view));

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (quitMi), "activate", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SuganGopalNyachhyon You are using Unity, is the menu bar being displayed in the system's top panel? That is where other GTK+ applications place their menus in Unity. You could try running the app under GNOME or another desktop, the menu bar should be displayed in those desktop environments.

Comment: its not displayed there too

Comment: @SuganGopalNyachhyon Well, it works for me: http://i.imgur.com/pOZsH3i.gif Have you tried it in another desktop environment?